# App to create photo tour using pictures and gpx tracks we already have

Tags: maps, photography

Is there a program, app or website, where you can:

1. Upload geolocated pictures from Google Drive or your phone gallery or computer
2. Upload gpx track
3. Edit the default music

The app should arrange the photos based on time and the gpx track and then create a photo tour with a map.

I have found komoot and polarstep that do this if you use the app to capture the trip and images but I want to use something to create this with images I already have.

Here's an example where I used [komoot](https://www.komoot.com/tour/t87113913?ref=atd) and JournI

Comment: What's GPX? Something derived from GPS I'm guessing?

Comment: @hippietrail [GPS Exchange Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) is a data format for describing GPS waypoints, routes and tracks.

Comment: There's a software recs stack exchange which might fit this question better.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas thanks - how can we move it there?